# Share Point - create permission level and set it as read-only

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions

I create a custom permission level and set it to a site collection programmatically.
Is it possible to define it as a read only such as OOB permission level, for example:"Full Control", "Contribute"..
I have to block user from changing/deleting/copying the custom permission level that was set programmatically

Answer (score 1):

As long as the user doesn't have "Manage Permission" rights, they will not be able edit permission levels for a site. Look for the below checkbox in the permission level you have assigned them[image]

I hope this helps

Comment: In general I want to give users the option to create new permission level.but those that were set programmatically I want to block users from edit/delete.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the permissions level page, and determine which options you want selected